# How to merge several css files into one in webpack 4?

Tags: css, node.js, webpack

I want to compose one main.css file from several css files. How can I make this using webpack 4?

[image]

This is my webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/app.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: []
};
```

Comment: What's your actual webpack configuration?

Answer (score -1):

Webpack has some awesome tools available for merging files into one, I would suggest you using .scss files and let those merge into css files. However that is your own preferred issue.

Please take a look at this plugin to merge multiple css files into one.
https://github.com/oklas/merge-webpack-plugin

A better understanding can be found at this post as well: https://medium.com/trabe/multiple-css-bundles-with-webpack-75f263095f09

Comment: I've already tried using example from this site, but it doesn't work for Webpack 4. Officil docs recommend use mini-css-extract-plugin. But, I did't understand how to implement my task using this plugin.

Comment: Are you able to use scss and compile it to css?

Comment: Also are you able to place the line of codes you tried?
https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/webpack/merge-multiple-css-into-single-file/

Comment: I can't use sass at this moment.

Comment: :warning: Since webpack v4 the extract-text-webpack-plugin should not be used for css. Use mini-css-extract-plugin instead.

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/extract-text-webpack-plugin/